# What's the most efficient way to adjust aspect ratio without Photoshop?

Tags: web, aspect-ratio

I need to find a simple way to adjust the aspect ratio of images that are submitted to my company's website. The design of the site is pretty punishing to any images that are not in 16:9. I just use the Photoshop crop tool to do this, but most other users either don't have a key or wouldn't know how to do this. I need to find a simple way to teach to users how to do this.

Can anyone recommend an alternative to Photoshop that has the ability to add margins to achieve a 16:9 aspect ratio?

Comment: Do you want to crop or add margins? Those are two very different problems.

Comment: Mostly add margins. Cropping seems to be no problem for most of the people I work with, but when it comes to "tall" images, they seem to get stumped. This in turn stumps the limited design of the website, which in turn  results in angry messages in my inbox.

Comment: Sounds like the best option would be software on the server, to automatically add margins and resize any images that are uploaded. Then it doesn't require any extra work from the users.

Answer (score 1):

If someone does not have Photoshop you can simply download https://www.gimp.org/ or http://www.getpaint.net/index.html which are free.

If someone does not how to do it, you have two options. They should not do it or learn how to do it.

---

Let us asume there are a ton of images to crop. In this case efficient is not the same as right.

Why? Because sometimes you need to make a decision on what part you need to crop, you need to refame.

But if you need to do that on a thousand images and you do not care much about the framing, you can use another free program like IrfanView and use the batch option. http://www.irfanview.com/

File > Batch conversion rename > Advanced > Crop.

But beware! If you do not know how to use it you can simply scr** a thousand images at the same time! Work on a copy of the images on a new folder.

---

One aditional thing. You are worried about the aspect ratio, but it is more important the size, so ask what size and compression the site will need.

Comment: I couldn't agree more that they should learn how to do things. Sadly, if I do not find a simple enough process for them, they will not learn, and I will have to continue to clean up other people's messes. GIMP seems like a good place to start though. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the image size is thankfully limited by the submission portal. The issue is that the responsive design goes haywire when "tall" images are uploaded. So, I suppose a simpler way to ask my question would be: what is a simple way to add margins to images without photoshop? The users seem to have cropping down, so that is less important.